# Can one autogenerate a protocols stubs

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Still waiting on my MacBook.

When an interface that I create references a protocol e.g. CCLocationManagerDelegate does the various methods get autogenerated or does intellisense pop up with all the available methods to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode doesn't do this unless the methods are in a template file (and I'm not aware of a template for a `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`.

That being said, you might want to check out [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html), which is a neat app that can do a whole bunch of code generation for you, of which (I believe) protocol conformance is a part.